# Listar mensagens de usuário logado usando Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde.

Tenho em meu Controller o método abaixo:

```
public function lista () {        
    $mensagens =  Auth::user()->mensagens()->get();
    $title= "Mensagens";
    return view('auth.mensagens.lista',compact('mensagens','title'));
}
```

Ele retorna uma lista de mensagens do usuário logado.
Acontece que em minha modelagem de dados, cada mensagem possui um status boolean 0 ou 1.
Como eu faço para que só retorne as mensagens com o status 1 ?

Deve ser algo bobo, mas hoje não consegui ver uma solução pra isso.

Grato

Comment: Por estar usando Laravel, acredito que você deva saber qual é o retorno de `Auth::user()->mensagens()`, correto? Se não sabe, comece pesquisando isso.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um `where` na sua consulta.

```
public function lista () {        
    $mensagens =  Auth::user()->mensagens()->where('status', 1)->get();
    $title= "Mensagens";

    return view('auth.mensagens.lista', compact('mensagens', 'title'));
}
```

Comment: Caramba... era isso que eu estava errando: where('status', 1)->get();